# No analogue audio on Raspi 2B when using Sonic Pi BUT can play .wav's using VLC

Tags: audio, output, sonic-pi

Note:
Boot pi - launch VLC and play .WAV using active speakers (and headphones)
Notice that Sonic Pi will not launch when VLC is running. I put this down to lack of RAM.
Close VLC -> launch Sonic Pi -> run basic program on Sonic Pi -> no audio.
Stumped

Answer (score 1):

Sonic Pi 3.1: as 'bundled' with the latest RaspiOs has an issue with the analogue (headphone) socket. This is supposed to have been fixed in the latest update to RaspiOS but from my experience this is not the the case. However SP3.2.2 appears to resolve the issue as I can now get sound from my analogue output